# Springboot with restful webserivces

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc

How to Integrate spring with Restful Web service in detail description

How to provide and consume services using it?

Please help me with detailed description .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the second part of this presentation I showed a Spring Boot REST server and how to deploy of an Angular app there:
https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=2322

Comment: Thank you I will go through that site

Answer (score 0):

There are rich resource on Spring official website. And you should take a look at this https://spring.io/guides.
I think that you can find out all the answers of your questions.

Comment: Thank you I will go through that site